# Using auto-completion/code-completion in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I wonder how I can make use of code-completion with ol3?

In debugging-tools like firebug I can use the completion
[image]

but I haven't figured out how to use the completion in an IDE.
( for OpenLayers2 it was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093764/enable-code-assist-for-openlayers-javascript-library )

Has anyone suggestions how to setup the OpenLayers3-code-completion / code assist in an IDE like AptanaStudio or Eclipse?

Comment: It is unclear what you want/need!

Comment: just updated the question to make it better understandable what I am looking for

Comment: I don't think so. And this is certainly not a GIS question.

Comment: It's 100% for sure a GIS question, but Web-GIS and not "old fashioned" Desktop-GIS. Ever wondered what these OpenLayers, GeoExt and JavaScript tags mean?

Comment: This is about editors. It has nothing to do with OpenLayers or others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it with Zend Studio and it works, so I guess it will also work with other IDE's, that can interpret the JSDOC3.

[image]